# Invalid argument @ rb_sysopen error using Nokogiri with Rails 5.2 on Windows server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nokogiri

I read several Q&A on StackOverflow or Internet, but did not find the solution to this issue. The context is important :

- Windows server 2016
- Rails 5.2.4
- Ruby 2.6.5
- Nokogiri 1.12.3-x64-mingw32

I wish to use Nokogiri to parse XML resources collected on the internet. The first step is to get the content from the url:

```
resource = Nokogiri::XML(open("https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/api/dissemination/sdmx/2.1/categoryscheme/ESTAT/AGRIC"))
```

But this raises the error:

```
Errno::EINVAL
Invalid argument @ rb_sysopen - https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/api/dissemination/sdmx/2.1/categoryscheme/ESTAT/AGRIC
```

I also tried the following, based on Nokogiri [tutorials](https://nokogiri.org/tutorials/parsing_an_html_xml_document.html#from-the-internets):

```
resource = Nokogiri::XML(URI.open("https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/api/dissemination/sdmx/2.1/categoryscheme/ESTAT/AGRIC"))
```

which raises the error: `private method 'open' called for URI:Module`

How can I provide the XML data to Nokogiri from the published API?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution consists in 2 steps:

1. I added the **open-uri** gem to my application's Gemfile, so that I can retrieve the content of resource URL.
2. I define the **proxy** option to *false* regarding my infrastructure

Then the Nokogiri document can be created:

```
resource = URI.open("https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/api/dissemination/sdmx/2.1/categoryscheme/ESTAT/AGRIC"), proxy: false)
document = Nokogiri::XML(resource)
```

The document can now be parsed.